# Atmosphere broadcast after http post (dropwizard)

Tags: dropwizard, atmosphere

I have a WebSocketHandlerService based on the chat example which works fine - messages sent by clients are broadcast to all other clients.

I'm setting the broadcaster on the resources by injecting the factory into the WebSocketHandlerService:

```
@Inject
private BroadcasterFactory factory;
```

and then setting in onOpen:

```
@Override
public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) throws IOException {        
    Broadcaster b = factory.lookup("/chat");
    webSocket.resource().setBroadcaster(b);
```

I now want to broadcast a message to all clients from another part of my DropWizard application, when a POST is made. I've tried getting the broadcaster like this:

```
BroadcasterFactory broadcasterFactory = 
    servlet.framework().getBroadcasterFactory();
Broadcaster b = factory.lookup("/chat");
```

But if I broadcast using this broadcaster non of the clients receive anything.

When I debug I can see it is not the same BroadcasterFactory or Broadcaster. How can I get a reference to the broadcaster which is used within the WebSocketHandlerService so I can use it for broadcasting from other parts of my application?

Thanks

Comment: By the sounds of it you want to bind your factory as a singleton into your application? What injection framework are you using?

Comment: I'm not actually using an injection framework in the dropwizard part of the app -  I was just  getting hold of the BroadcasterFactory when constructing the AtmosphereServlet in my dropwizard Application class. I was assuming this would be the same one that Atmosphere injects into the WebSocketHandlerService as described here: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-BroadcasterFactory-and-AtmosphereResourceFactory-with-2.2-and-newer (I'm using atmosphere 2.4.9)

Comment: So you want to have the same broadcastfactory in the resources used by DW. Can you add the code of the resource + the way you create your resources. I have no experience with the particular framework but to me it sounds like you need to wire up your jersey environment with the correct broadcastfactory.

Comment: yep agreed - I want to know how to get the broadcaster factory which atmosphere is injecting into the WebSocketHandlerService, so i can use the same one

Comment: I believe, for dropwizard, you would create your broadcaster factory in the run method of your application and then use the jersey integration to bind that instance, therefore enabling it for injection into all other resources automatically

Comment: Thanks for the help, I couldn't work out how to do that.
For now I've discovered the `Universe.broadcasterFactory()` method so I'm using that in both places and it seems to return the same factory each time, so I can move on

Comment: you can read up on injection for jersey here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html essentially you would create your broadcaster, then register an abstract binder and give it the same instance